# Docker client execution

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a very basic doubt regarding docker.
I have a docker host installed in **ubuntuA**.

So, to test this from the client(**UbuntuB**) , should the docker be installed in UbuntuB machine also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 
    you have to install docker on both client and server.

Answer (score 3):

More correct answer is "only docker client" need to be installed in **UbuntuB**

In UbuntuB, install `docker` client only, it is around 17M

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
# curl https://get.docker.io/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -o /usr/local/bin/docker
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker
```

In order to run `docker` command, you need talk to daemon in **ubuntuA** (port 2375 is used since docker 1.0)

```
$ docker -H tcp://ubuntuA:2375 images
or
$ export DOCKER_HOST tcp://ubuntuA:2375
$ docker images
```

see more detail in http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/